# Python freeopcua server: how to know number of connected clients?

Tags: python, server, opc

I have successfully set-up a freeopcua server and it communicates well with clients but now I would like to know how many clients are connected to my server. Is there a method or workaround to know how many clients are connected to a freeopcua server?

Answer (score 1):

For OPC UA it should be in `Server/ServerDiagnostics/ServerDiagnosticsSummary/CurrentSessionCount`

But afaik there is absolutely no code included about all this Diagnostics-Stuff neither in `python-opcua` nor in `opcua-asyncio`.

A workaround would be to implement it and pull request.. haha

You can check for established connections, something like `netstat -anp | grep :4840 | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l`. In Py3 you could do something similar with `psutil.net_connections()` and also filter for Port and `ESTABLISHED`. [Docs](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.net_connections)

### EDIT: Win 10

`netstat -a -o -n -b | findstr 4840 | findstr ESTABLISHED`

Btw. the Established thing is localized in Windows.. so maybe must be replaced.

So if all Clients share the same IP it is a little bit harder if they open multiple sockets each due to the fact you can't sort out connections from same source IP. If they do so imho the only option is to implement the ServerDiagnostics stuff in the lib.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Win10 with all the clients on the same PC so part of your great workaround is not applicable. Anyway I will try to apply your sugestions. Thank you again

Comment: Check edit please